# x86 assembly (masm32) output multiplied number produces junk characters

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I'm coming back to assembly for the sake of it after a few months and I'm having trouble getting two numbers to multiply and output the result. Here's my code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap :none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data 
     sum sdword 0
.code 
start:
mov ecx, 6        
xor eax, eax                  
mov edx, 7               
mul edx                  
push eax
pop sum
lea eax, sum
call StdOut
push 0 
call ExitProcess
end start
```

It outputs something like `P &aeffiini,`.

QUESTION: Why does it output that random character string, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any code to convert the result (a number) to a string so it's ready to print out. `StdOut` (probably) isn't a function, so calling it is going to take some semi-random value, treat it as an address, and call that address -- almost certainly not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because StdOut prints NULL terminated strings NOT numbers.  You need to convert the number to a string first.  MASM32 has dwtoa.  Also, your multiplying wrong.  you multiply with eax

```
include masm32rt.inc

.data?
lpBuffer    db 12 dup (?)

.code 
start:
    mov     ecx, 6        
    mov     eax, 7               
    mul     eax    

    push    offset lpBuffer
    push    eax
    call    dwtoa 

    push    offset lpBuffer             
    call    StdOut

    inkey
    push    0 
    call    ExitProcess
end start
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Out of interest, why do you need to do `push offset lpBuffer`? And what is `inkey`?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is controlled by whatever you have in the `StdOut` function, which you haven't shown us. More than likely (given your description), it takes the character *code* in the accumulator and outputs the equivalent character.

If that's the case, what you probably need to do is to take the value in `eax` and work out which characters need to be output based on that. Then, call `StdOut` for each of them.

The pseudo-code for that would be something like:

```
eax <- value to print
call print_num
exit

print_num:
    compare eax with 0
    branch if not equal, to non_zero

    eax <- hex 30                       ; Number was zero,
    jump to StdOut                      ;   just print single digit 0

non_zero:
    push eax, ebx, ecx                  ; Save registers that we use
    ecx <- 0                            ; Digit count
loop1:
    compare eax with 0                  ; Continue until digits all pushed
    jump if equal, to num_pushed

    increment ecx                       ; Another digit
    ebx <- eax                          ; Work out what it is
    eax <- eax / 10
    eax <- eax * 10
    ebx <- ebx - eax
    push ebx to stack                   ; Then push it,
    jump to loop1                       ;  and carry on

num_pushed:
    pop eax from stack                  ; Get next digit
    eax <- eax + hex 30                 ; Print it out
    call StdOut
    decrement ecx                       ; One less digit to go
    jump if not zero, to num_pushed     ; Continue if more

    pop ecx, ebx, eax from stack        ; Clean up stack and return
    return
```

If that's *not* the case, you will simply have to figure out what `StdOut` actually does and adjust your code to meet the requirements of that function.